# create aggreate column that find the sum of transaction on that particular date selected from parameter

Tags: tableau-api

[`[enter image description here][1]`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AWhQ.png)how can I create two different column showing sum of transaction on that particular date in tableau and then how can I find variance f those transaction date's amount..
here is how my tableau's snapshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM3SM.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Kindly explain your problem in more detail to make it easier for users to help you out.

Comment: Try sum( if date = parameter then  amount end)

Comment: I am creating a balance sheet for which I need to find the variance of amounts between the selected 2 dates.I have applied a filter to calculate the total balance for a particular date but don't know how to create a new col for another selected date and then find the total balance on that date.

Comment: No @Bermado it showing an error that sum is beign called with Boolean.did u mean float??